# Hibernate doesn't generate cascade

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, jpa, cascade

I have a set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to create so that Hibernate creates the tables in mysql for me.

However, it doesn't seem that hibernate correctly adds `Cascade` on the references in the table. **It does however work when I for instance delete a row, and I have a delete cascade as hibernate annotation**. So I guess that means that Hibernate reads the annoation on runtime, and perform cascading manually?

Is that normal behavior?

For instance:

```
@Entity
class Report {
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public File getPdf() {
    return pdf;
}
}
```

Here I have set cascade to ALL. However, when running `show create table Report`

```
Report | CREATE TABLE `Report` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pdf_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK91B14154FDE6543A` (`pdf_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK91B14154FDE6543A` FOREIGN KEY (`pdf_id`) REFERENCES `File` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

It doesn't say anything about cascading other then the foreign key. In my opinion, it should have added the `ON DELETE CASCADE ON DELETE UPDATE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CascadeType` and `@Cascade` definitions are **not** translated into DDL, they tell Hibernate how to behave when an operation is performed.

However, there is [`@OnDelete`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/OnDelete.html) that you can use on the parent to get the foreign key created with the appropriate on delete cascade clause.